# Using the CRR Binomial Equity Option pricer in fOptions for American options

Tags: r, finance, quantitative-finance

I am using the `CRRBinomialTreeOption` function in the `fOptions` package to price American options. For example:

```
CRRBinomialTreeOption("pa",24.5,27.01,0.7479452,r = 0.02,0,0.235999,n=100,NULL,NULL)
```

However, this is producing results that are significantly different from what I expect. For example using those inputs I get a price of `3.071618` compared to an expected price of `4.04`. I have also tried using `b=0` and get `3.546099`, which is still reasonably different from what I expect.

All my inputs have been verified and are valid, however I suspect that I have misunderstood the `b` parameter. I have interpreted the parameter as the dividend yield, however in the documentation it is described as the annualized cost of carry.

Have I misunderstood this parameter? If so, how should I interpret the parameter for equity options? If I haven't misunderstood that parameter, can anyone suggest another reason as to why I am not getting my expected output?

Comment: How do you calculate your expected price of 4.04?

Comment: @Pascal It is the official closing price for the option with those inputs on 31/12/15

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking at this in the future, the answer to the above problem is that the b parameter in the `CRRBinomialTreeOption` function is actually the cost of carry, i.e. the risk free rate less the income earned on the asset. This seems as though you are inputting the risk free rate twice: 1) in the r parameter and 2) in the b parameter, which is the source of confusion. Nevertheless, this approach means that IF there is no income earned on the asset r=b, otherwise, r = risk free rate and b = risk free rate - dividend yield if it is a stock option. E.g.

```
CRRBinomialTreeOption(TypeFlag = "pa",
                  S = 24.5
                  X = 27.01
                  Time = 0.7479452
                  r = 0.02,
                  b = 0.02 - 0.0635,
                  sigma = 0.235999
                  n=100)@price
```

Which gives me `4.05` versus the expected `4.04`. The difference of 1 cent is likely due to slightly different market forward dividend curve expectations and/or the risk free rate reflecting the forward curve. In this particular case a dividend yield of `0.0625` compared to `0.0635` solves for the price almost exactly.

Comment: So how do you get your expected value? Please show how to use `CRRBinomialTreeOption` to get it.

Comment: The expected value @Pascal is the official market closing price for the option, it is not something that I personally derived, therefore I can't tell you how I got it aside from it being the official market closing price. I've added an example to make it clearer what I did